# Dropdown menu stopped working, changing overflow doesn't fix it

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Couple of days ago my dropdown menu stopped working, the dropdown works if the navmenu have more height but don't work like is intended.

Tried changing the header section to overflow hidden and vice versa and deactivating all the plugins one by one but doesn't seems to fix the problem. Neither changing the z-index to 999.

Can someone help me?

https://equis.org.mx/ in the "Áreas de trabajo" section.

Answer (score 0):

There's your problem:

```
.elementor-widget-container {
   overflow: hidden !important;
}
```